# How to add inbound rule to AWS default VPC security group using boto

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I want to add inbound rules to my default vpc security group using boto. But i find no proper documentation to do so. Does it possible to do? can anyone help?

Comment: Yes http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html

Comment: thanks but i need to add inbound rules using python. i know only boto module has access to aws vpc. so how should i do?

Answer (score 3):

Here under the group_ids use the sg-id of the default security; which you can get from the AWS management console.

```
import boto
ec2 = boto.connect_ec2()
sg = ec2.get_all_security_groups(group_ids='sg-12345')[0]
sg.authorize(ip_protocol="-1", from_port=None, to_port=None, cidr_ip="0.0.0.0/0", src_group=None, dry_run=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

python has boto.vpc module to work with vpc. but to modify or add inbound rules to security group you have to use boto.ec2 module.